# How to use WordPress $wpdb without including a file that sends http headers?

Tags: php, http-headers, phpexcel, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include wp-blog-header.php without headers so I can use phpexcel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969916/include-wp-blog-header-php-without-headers-so-i-can-use-phpexcel)

I'm trying to use `$wpdb` results to output an excel file w/ `Phpexcel`, however as you might guess there are header wars raging.  Is it possible to use `$wpdb` without including a file that sets headers already? How? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried including wp-blog-header.php? (I don't think that sends headers, but I might be wrong.) You should be able to use $wpdb then.

Comment: shoot, my bad. Then, have you considered just connecting to and querying the database on your script directly?

Comment: @mno4k for some reason that doesn't work either - it just returns different results - absolutely boggles my mind? I wonder if wp sets some wierd thing on the db somehow. If I run the query from phpmyadmin's sql panel it returns the results fine, but when I run it from a standard `mysql_query` it doesn't return the results. Crazyness!

Comment: That does sound pretty crazy. Could you post the code you used to run your query?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this which doesn't send headers:

```
require_once '/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php';
```

Example which works and outputs no errors:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

echo "Hello<br />";

require_once '/PATH/TO/wp-load.php';

echo "After require...<br />";

var_dump($wpdb);
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: In what way?  I use that all the time to get the `$wpdb` object and issue queries.  Do you get errors or what?  It might help if you post your code so we know what method you used that didn't work and output headers.

Comment: blank - server is messed up, no error reporting...

Comment: Did you make sure to change the `require_once` call to reference the actual correct location of `wp-load.php` which is found in your Wordpress root directory?

Comment: this solution works well for my situation. From within a custom template in my child theme, the path is `require_once 'wp-load.php';`